# How can I open camera on mobile phone on a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, camera, qr-code

I'm having a trouble on accessing the camera on my mobile device through web app. In web, the camera works fine, but when I use my mobile device, the camera wont show **BUT** when I add `https://` in the url the camera will show and be available to access. how can I solve this problem? I need to access my mobile camera.

I'm working on a QR Code. In Web it works fine. but when in camera I need to type `https://` on the url to access the camera.

How can i solve this? do I need to add any functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/ you can find a warning as follows:
[image: Warning note]
So no. The only way to 'solve' your problem is to use HTTPS.

Comment: Hollan, that's a lot of info thank you. but one more thing.. so there is no way I can use a real-time qr code reader by scanning the image? how can I do it? should I just do it on the platform of mobile app development and not on web app development?

Comment: Austen Holland , may I ask this last question tho? I haven't tried it on tablet since I dont have one xD.. I tried the QR Code reader on my Mobile Device and it DID NOT work cause it requires an HTTPS.. however do you think it will work on Tablet Device? I tried to put my computer to tablet mode and qr code worked without an https.. but on the actual tablet device.. do you think it will work? thank you please response for the last time

Comment: @webxcoding Using a physical tablet should result in the same requirements as a mobile device. An SSL certificate can be obtained at no cost to you if you use https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: thanks it's getting clearer for me now.. but is that ssl secured?

Comment: @webxcoding The only difference between a free SSL certificate like LetsEncrypt and a commercial one you pay for is insurance, and the length it's valid for. LetsEncrypt certificates are designed for automation, and are only valid for 3 months at a time. While Commercial certificates are valid for 1 or 2 years depending on what you purchase. Here is a good article with more detail on the differences: https://moz.com/blog/traditional-vs-lets-encrypt-vs-cloudflare

Comment: what if I use an SSL on a localhost server and not on a website that is deployed? is there a possibility that `https` will work on a localhost?

Comment: SSL works on localhost just as it would work on a public web server. However, as it is not possible to obtain a localhost certificate from a Certificate Authority, you would simply need to use a self signed certificate and accept the SSL warning on visiting the page.

Comment: what do you mean sir? I can type `https://` on local server yes? BUT NOT able to obtain or make one on a pubic web server that has a domain name right? like for example I have this `https://localhost/sample.php` I can do this right but it is not obtainable.. it is impossible to register an ssl on that example am i right/

Comment: For more information on SSL with localhost, give this a read: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/